# How to convert .caffemodel into .mat format

Tags: deep-learning, caffe, matconvnet

I wanted to use my fine-tuned caffe model in matconvnet for further processing. But the script provided by Andrea vedaldi at 
https://github.com/vlfeat/matconvnet/blob/master/utils/import-caffe.py
leaves the following errors which I am not able to fix:

google.protobuf.text_format.ParseError: 8:1 : Message type "caffe.NetParameter" has no field named "layer".

When I include my caffe.proto file in the argument to import-caffe.py it leaves the following error

google.protobuf.text_format.ParseError: 8:1 : Message type "caffe.NetParameter" has no field named "layer".

I would be grateful if any researcher might have already solved this issue.

Thanks in advance
Tharun

Comment: what `caffe-variant` argument you are using?

Comment: I have passed argument as --caffe-variant=caffe. The caffe.proto file is the one at the link  https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2a8WzvR-lOxbXBNd2NXVERYS2c/view?usp=sharing

Comment: try `caffe-old` what do you get?

Comment: I forgot to include an output type= simplenn argument which I did now and I get a different error posted below irrespective of --caffe-variant as caffe or caffe-old chosen I get the same error    Loading ../face_full_conv.prototxt
Loading Caffe CNN parameters from ../face_full_conv.caffemodel
Converting 0 layers
Input image data tensor shape:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/tharun/matconvnet/matconvnet-1.0-beta23/utils/import-caffe.py", line 776, in <module>
    print "Input image data tensor shape:", dataShape
NameError: name 'dataShape' is not defined

Comment: please [format](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) your question.

Answer (score 1):

Basically the error message says that the field named layer doesn't exist in the prototxt file. It's probably a typo. Check the prototxt file at line 8 column 1. My guess is that the name of the field should be layers.

Good luck!